# build nested attribute if it exists increase quantity by 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my form setup like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @line_item do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :product_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: @product.id } %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :line_item_attributes do |attributes_form| %>
      <%= attributes_form.association :product_attribute, collection: @product.product_attributes %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

and my create action looks like this:

```
  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:line_item][:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

now I'd essentially like to expand it so I can build the nested attributes for `line_item`. The small catch is if the item exists already I wish for the record not to be created, but instead += 1. I'm thinking I have to maybe create a method, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might not need extra method.

```
def create
  product = Product.find(params[:line_item][:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build do |line_item|
    line_item.product = product 
    line_item.product_attribute = ProductAttribute.where(...).first || line_item.build_product_attribute()
  end

  ...
end
```

The line `line_item.product_attribute = ProductAttribute.where(...).first || line_item.build_product_attribute()` assigns existing `product_attribute` based on the conditions supplied in `where(...)` if found.  If not found, we build a new `product_attribute` with `line_item.build_product_attribute`.